# How can I pass data from Angular front end to spring boot back end?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a spring boot code that takes 2 parameters to perform some calculations and return some values. I tested it in the browser and the API is working properly. Now I am trying to connect my Spring boot API to Angular. How do I send the user input (2 parameters) to the spring boot back-end, process the data and return the results to Angular to show them in the front end?

```
  retrieveData(currency:string, amount: number){
    return this.http.get<convert[]>. 
    (`http://localhost:8080/convert/${currency}/${amount}`);
  }
```

Above you can find my method in Angular which retrieves the data. The parameters will be provided in the UI by the user. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

In your `component.ts` in `onsubmit()`

```
this.abcService.abcreg(this.form.value)
```

Your `abcService.ts` file should be like this.

```
  #Imports 
   
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class abcService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type':'application/json'
    })
  }

abcreg(abc:abcreg):Observable<any>{

const uploadData = new FormData();

uploadData.append('requestparam1',abc.Name);

uploadData.append('requestparam2',abc.Address);

return this.httpClient.post(environment.api_url+'save_data', uploadData)

}
```